# Confusion with "ir de/al/a la/a un/a una" phrases

Tags: gramática

I have learned that following phrases are correct:

```
ir al cine
ir de excursión
ir a una exposición
```

I do not understand when to use ir de/al/a la/a un/a una.

- Why dont we use "ir de cine" or "ir a un cine"?
- Why dont we use "ir a la excursión" or "ir a una excursión"?
- Why dont we use "ir a la exposición" or "ir de exposición"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that **cine** and **exposición** is a specific place and **excursion** is an activity. So, with an *specific place* you should use **a** and with *activities* you should use **de**.

> Ir **a**l cine. (al is a contraction of **a** + **el**)
>   ir **a** la exposición
>   ir **a** la escuela
>   ir **a**l club

Only in these cases, you should add the article (i.e. el, la, los, las, un, una, unos, unas.)

> Esta noche iré a *el cine* (Is not correct to write **a** + **el** but **al** instead)
>   Mañana iré a *la escuela*
>   quiero ir a *la exposición*
>   quiero ir a *los estadios*
>   mañana iré a *unos talleres*
>   ayer fui a *unas* exposiciones

So it is correct to say

> ir **a** *un cine*
>   ir **a** *una exposición*
>   ir **a** *una excursión*

because you use an indefinite article meaning that, for example, you go to a movie theater. You don't specify which theater though.

---

With activities (but not verbs) you should use **de**

> Ir **de** compras
>   ir **de** excursión
>   ir **de** vacaciones
>   ir **de** juerga

---

If it is an action (a verb) you should use **a**

> Ir **a** comprar
>   ir **a** jugar
>   ir **a** comer
>   ir **a** descansar
>   ir **a** celebrar

Comment: +1.Although is correct too "ir **de** cine", since "de cine" means "really well" (A los que compraron acciones de Inditex les está yendo **de cine**, porque han subido un 30%".

Comment: In México we also have similar expressions to denote how good or bad it went: Ayer me fue **de** la patada; todo me salió mal. (It went too badly)